# tox could not find executable 'rmdir'

Tags: python, tox

I am trying to create a `tox.ini` file that runs my tests, clears previous coverages, and creates a coverage. I want to delete the previous `htmlcov` folder, by `rmdir /S /Q htmlcov`.

The error I get is: `ERROR: InvocationError for command could not find executable 'rmdir'`, however, the command works in the command line.

Can someone explain why?

Here is my `tox.ini` file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py35


[testenv]
deps = pytest
       coverage

commands = pytest
           coverage erase
           rmdir /S /Q htmlcov
           coverage run --branch __main__.py test
           coverage report --omit='.tox/*,venv/*,tests/'
           coverage html --omit='.tox/*,venv/*,tests/'
```

Comment: try with `/bin/rmdir`

Comment: Which OS? On Windows `rmdir` isn't an executable but a shell command.

Comment: @MichaelButscher windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows use instead

```
cmd /c rmdir...
```

Comment: `cmd /C if exist htmlcov rmdir /S /Q htmlcov`